# configure reverse proxy for subdomain but keep domain for links

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have a website (developed in ruby on rails + angularJS and running on nginx + unicorn) where users can access few pages through differents URIs. For example, www.example.com/1234 and 1234.example.com load the same content.

The problem is links in 1234.example.com don't work properly, because these links depend on host, and 1234.example.com is not a valid host for that.

My nginx conf for subdomains is like that:

```
server {
    root /var/www/example.com/current/public;
    server_name 1234.example.com;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

    location / {
        add_header Set-Cookie qid=1234;
        proxy_pass https://www.example.com/1234;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For;
        proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        alias /var/www/example.com/current/public/assets/;
        proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
    }

    location ~ /(library|categories) {
       proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
    }
}
```

Cookie and location directives "/assets/" and "~ /(library|categories)" are required for load all content.

So, I need set host as 1234.example.com only for the "/" location, but in any other case, the host sould be www.example.com.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

An nginx way would be to use a map:

```
map $http_host $sitevar {
   1234.example.com "1234";
   default "";
}

if ($sitevar = 1234) {
   rewrite ^ /1234 permanent;
}
```

and set your cookie with `qid=$sitevar`

You then set your server_name to a wildcard:

```
server_name .example.com;
```

For that matter you could do that and handle the routing in code as you can pass the variable as part of the request.

Comment: I can not use rewrite because I need keep url as "1234.example.com" when visitor has typed 1234.example.com.

Comment: Thinking about it, using proxy_pass should work but you may have to pass $uri to get the right page. However, I would also look at making the code respond to hostnames correctly as it would make life a lot easier.